# Putting $variable string into "string"

Tags: php, string, variables

I have question because i think i doing unnecessary job.

e.g.

```
$phone = "222-333-444"
echo "Phone number is " . $phone;

$phone['2'] = "222-333-444"
echo "Phone number is " . $phone['2'];
```

Please explain is there ANY ANY ANY reason to do it the way above rather than"

```
$phone = "222-333-444"
echo "Phone number is $phone";

$phone['2'] = "222-333-444"
echo "Phone number is $phone['2']";
```

Comment: The latter one (with the array) won't work. You will need to use `echo "Phone number is {$phone['2']}";`

Comment: Full Disclosure I don't like PHP:

For me it's less readable. I'm likely to skip over it when reading the code. Assuming it's just a string.

Comment: FYE: The first is "concatenation", the second "interpolation".

Answer (score 1):

Both are right ways to print a variable. There's no right or wrong, just different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

No, actually both are equivalent. I personally always write this, because for me it is far more explicit:

```
echo "Phone number is " . $phone['2'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason would be consistency and clarity.  Concatenation is faster than interpolation, but the difference is so negligible it should not define your choice.  I prefer the second personally.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not difference.

second example should be like this:

```
$phone = "222-333-444"
echo "Phone number is {$phone}";

$phone['2'] = "222-333-444"
echo "Phone number is {$phone['2']}";
```

Comment: `{}` are only necessary when the variable is an array and you want to specify an index. For plain variables, `{}` are optional.

Comment: @Kolink: I think, `{}` notation is always better to prevent mistakes.

Comment: Or if you can't use a space: `I like $somevars` vs `I like {$somevar}s`

Comment: what if its constant will it work with echo "this is {CONSTANT}";?

Comment: @MrSchmittt no, according to manual, you have to use `echo "this is".constant("CONSTANT");` or `echo "this is ".CONSTANT;` http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no reason at all, unless your variable is an array and you need to access a specific index.

Comment: You can access a specific index both ways.